# Remove XXX only as there is no other word in front of it

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that removes one word and one word before match which works pretty much good - `(?i)\s*\S+\s+\bXXX\b`

I need adjust this regular expression, so it removes XXX only as there is no other word in front of it. So if I have

> XXX ABC

, it outputs " ABC".

Comment: What do you mean by no other word before it? You mean there is no other word character `\w` before `XXX`?

Comment: I mean if string starts with XXX then just remove XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?i)(?:\s*\S+\s+)?\bXXX\b
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YsZvyq/1)

I just made this `(?:\s*\S+\s+)?` optional

Comment: Cool answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> I mean if string starts with XXX then just remove XXX

Then just match `^XXX` and replace the matches with the empty string.

```
var regex = new Regex("^XXX");
regex.Replace("XXX ABC", "")
```

If you want to match `XXX` with any non-word character behind it, e.g.

```
",XXX ABC" -> ", ABC"
"    XXX ABC" -> "     ABC"
```

Try this regex instead:

```
^(\W*)XXX
```

And replace with `$1`.